# How to download packages without using the software center?

Tags: software-center, proxy, downloads

Where can I manually download stuff from (in a user friendly way) without using the Ubuntu software center?

And if that's not possible, how can I fix the proxy restrictions of the software center. It doesn't seem to work at the only place where I have good internet access although all other sites work perfectly fine.

Answer (score 3):

You will first wish to install aptitude, which is a front end to the various apt utilities.

`sudo apt-get install aptitude`

then

`sudo aptitude install myprogram`

You can `aptitude search myprogram`, too.

`sudo aptitude update` will sync your computers lists of programs available with the main servers at Ubuntu.

And `sudo aptitude upgrade` will download and install any new versions of programs you have already.

Those last 2 commands can be joined together to make installing all the bug fixes and new versions very easy:

`sudo aptitude update && sudo aptitude -y upgrade`

Be aware that `-y` option means it won't ask you for confirmation. Usually not a problem, but you never know.
`

Answer (score 0):

Apart from `aptitude`, already signaled in another answer, you could use `apt-get`:

```
sudo apt-get --download-only --reinstall install <package names>
```

The `--reinstall` flag is required if a package is already installed, in which case `apt-get` do not want to download. The downloaded packages will be found in `/var/cache/apt/archives`.

Another option is the following

```
apt-get --print-uris install <package names>
```

it will give web addresses of packages to download. In this case, no way to get the url of already installed packages.

To extract the urls you can do

```
apt-get --print-uris install <package names> |
  awk -F\' '/http/ { print $2 }'
```

and to directly download the packages:

```
wget $(apt-get --print-uris install <package names> |
  awk -F\' '/http/ { print $2 }')
```