# Ubuntu 11.10 Software Center (proxy?)

Tags: software-center, proxy

I am unable to install software using the Software Center at work.  A nearly identical install of 11.10 at home works fine.  I suspect the proxy settings are the problem, as they are used at work, but not at home.  The system at work does browse the web and respond appropriately to nslookup's.

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/41688/how-to-download-packages-without-using-the-software-center

Answer (score 2):

Create or edit `/etc/apt/apt.conf` defining your proxy configuration_

```
Acquire::http::Proxy "http://username:password@proxy_name_or_ip:port/";
Acquire::https::Proxy "https://username:password@proxy_name_or_ip:port/";
Acquire::ftp::Proxy "ftp://username:password@proxy_name_or_ip:port/";
```

You could ignore the username and password if you make no use of they, and you could ignore https or ftp in the same way.

This is based on [a comment](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/software-center/+bug/545134/comments/13) in a ticket reporting this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Search for "network proxy" in Dash. Fill out your proxy details and set it system wide. Now, the software center can get the required packages via proxy server you set.

Comment: In Ubuntu 11.10 the system wide **proxy setting** is done via the **network settings**. And i still have the same problem after setting the proxy.