# How to download apps and install them on another machine

Tags: 12.10, package-management, downloads

I would like to install a program on another Ubuntu machine that does not have internet access. Is there a place that i can download Debian files, or can i copy some files out of my file system or what.
 I can't figure anything out!
thanks

Comment: Also, you may want to view this [community wiki article](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingSoftware#Installing_packages_without_an_Internet_connection).

Comment: [this](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/) is a recent website (i think) and it has a lot of .deb packages on it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can either find the links to individual packages, following the [instructions given in this answer to a similar question](https://askubuntu.com/a/52995/58950), which, in summary, are (credits to @enzotib):

```
apt-get --print-uris install <package names>
```

> it will give web addresses of packages to download. In this case, no way to get the url of already installed packages.
>
> To extract the urls you can do

```
apt-get --print-uris install <package names> |
awk -F\' '/http/ { print $2 }'
```

> and to directly download the packages:

```
wget $(apt-get --print-uris install <package names> |
awk -F\' '/http/ { print $2 }')
```

However, I use [keryx](http://keryxproject.org/) following a procedure I describe in [another question](https://askubuntu.com/a/181913/58950). I prefer this method because it detects what packages have an update, and lets me install additional packages taking care at the same time of dependencies.

For simply updating your system, you can find other options described elsewhere in this website and others.